# Can't assign int32 protobuf to int in Go lang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

So in my protobuf I have a message object

```
message HelloReply {
    int32 response = 1;
}
```

And I try to assign the response to a variable

```
var resp = 0
resp = helloReply.Response
```

I got an error saying

```
cannot use helloReply.Response (type int32) as type int in assignment
```

P.S I'm really new to Go and Protobuf. I'm sorry if this is too basic. I already search for the solution but I think I can't find the right keyword. So I really need your help guys :(

Comment: you can create `var resp int32` to assign int32 value to `resp` variable

Comment: @Himanshu OMG thankyou! I just found this answer on another question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `resp` variable of int32 type and assign `helloReply.Response` to resp variable. Like this

```
var resp int32
resp = helloReply.Response
```